# How can detect gmail command+enter button in the compose mail body?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail, hotkeys

I am creating a chrome extension and now I am facing issue regarding the hotkey. I am using backbone js framework. Basically when I click command+enter hotkey event in the body its does not work but its work on the toolbar.

Comment: show code.  explain in more detail what you tried and what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am overwriting gmail send feature, instead calling my own set of code and then send the mail. However all the functionality works fine with cursors. The issue I am facing with hotkeys. When we press command+enter, gmail sends that mail. So issue is I want to prevent that event instead call my function. But I am not able to detect the hotkeys.

Comment: search "block keypress event javascript" in google.  have the keypress event block all keypresses when your user is pressing ctrl, and run your function instead in your content script.